# Using Helvetica Neue in WatchKit not working, other custom fonts work

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

I am wanting to use Helvetica Neue Ultra Light in my `Watchkit` app. I have followed all of the instructions for adding a custom font (added to Extension bundle and added in Info.plist for Extension and Watchkit app), but NOTHING is working and it will never get used.

Really strange thing is, other `ttf` fonts that I have added DO work, it seems to just be some strange issue with Helvetica.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Where is Helvetica, and why can't I add it?**

**Edit:** To clear things up and prevent what people think might be obvious answers.

> Watchkit only includes the system font (San Francisco), it doesn't
>   expose all of the fonts that iOS has. (Ref:
>   [devforums.apple.com/message/1096179#1096179](http://devforums.apple.com/message/1096179#1096179)) THIS is why I am trying
>   to include Helvetica.

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to manually include HelveticaNeue? It should be included in the SDK.

Comment: @Fennelouski - Watchkit only includes the system font (San Francisco), it doesn't expose all of the fonts that iOS has. (Ref: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1096179#1096179) THIS is why I am trying to include Helvetica.

Comment: This is interesting. Have you tried importing another `.ttf` font that should be supported natively. I say should as I've used http://iosfonts.com/ for a quick reference to iOS fonts.

Comment: @Fennelouski - Other weights in the Helvetica family don't work either. You say "Natively". There is only ONE native font in `Watchkit`.

Comment: use attributed string and then use HelveticaNeue font through code. It will work

Comment: @SamB - Still not working. Do you have it working?

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

I had the same issue. I fixed it by including the `-` character between the font name and the name of its weight. In some ways, Xcode could recognize the font.

Try changing `HelveticaNeueUltraLight.ttf` into `HelveticaNeue-UltraLight.ttf` wherever possible (info.plist file and in the project folder).

### Option 2

Open up the FontBook that comes included within your Mac. Install the font if you haven't already and look closely at the *PostScript name* of the font. If it differs from the name you are currently using in Xcode, then change it.

[image]

### Option 3

If you can't still get this working, download the same font from another source.

Comment: Did you actually get it to work? Adding the `-` in the file name didn't work for me.

Comment: And how are you setting the font? In your Watchkit Interface.storyboard? Or as an `attributedString` programmatically?

Comment: In the Storyboard interface but I can't see why you can't do it programmatically.

Comment: ^ Same here, I've tried a few sources, TTF and OTF, checked the name, etc. Other fonts fine, I'm trying to add UltraLight, too. `Custom (none installed).`